# plot with two Y-axis of different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I'm trying to build a plot in R with 2 Y-axis. It is a rather regular task in Excel, but a good adventure in R.

So, here is my dataset:

| Date | Latvia | Lithuania | Poland | Russian Federation | Ukraine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 77.21 | 67.97 | 72.97 | 71.41 | 148.29 |
| 2013 | 75.40 | 65.62 | 72.83 | 71.03 | 149.45 |
| 2014 | 75.10 | 63.86 | 71.55 | 72.95 | 153.65 |
| 2015 | 68.77 | 59.54 | 65.86 | 71.61 | 162.92 |
| 2016 | 64.80 | 55.83 | 62.14 | 69.70 | 154.51 |
| 2017 | 63.81 | 54.14 | 60.80 | 70.29 | 153.99 |
| 2018 | 62.88 | 53.31 | 59.62 | 70.82 | 153.07 |
| 2019 | 62.36 | 51.94 | 58.12 | 71.18 | 150.26 |
| 2020 | 63.89 | 51.69 | 58.94 | 73.00 | 154.26 |
| 1Q2021 | 65.36 | 51.25 | 57.78 | 72.69 | 156.25 |

I need to build a chart with 5 lines:

- data points for Latvia, Lithuania, Poland and Russia on one Y axis,
- data points for Ukraine - on another.

I use the following part of the code to read and prepare the data for the chart:

1. Rear data from the Excel file:

```
data_3.2 <- read.xlsx(
"BEO_charts.xlsx", 
sheet = 22,
rows = c(25:33),
cols = c(2:7),
colNames = FALSE,
skipEmptyRows = TRUE,
skipEmptyCols = TRUE,
detectDates = TRUE
)

colnames(data_3.2) <- c(
  "date",
  "Latvia",
  "Lithuania",
  "Poland",
  "RF",
  "Ukraine"
)
```

2. Then I prepare a dataset for the part of the chart with 4 data points for the primary Y axis:

```
p3.2left <- 
  subset.data.frame(
  data_3.2, 
  select = c(
    "date",
    "Latvia",
    "Lithuania",
    "Poland",
    "RF")
  ) %>% 
  
  melt(
    id.vars = 'date', 
    variable.name = "GDP_var",
    value.name = "GDP_val",
    measure.vars = c(
      "Latvia",
      "Lithuania",
      "Poland",
      "RF")
    ) %>% 
  
  ggplot(
    aes (
      x = date, 
      y= GDP_val,
      group = GDP_var,
      colour = GDP_var
      )
    ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(50,80), breaks = seq(50,80,5), expand = c(0.025,0), position = "left")+
  #scale_x_date(date_breaks = )
  labs (x = "", y = "") +
  geom_line(size = 1)+ 
  scale_colour_manual (
    guide = "legend", 
    name = NULL,
    breaks = c(
      "Latvia",
      "Lithuania",
      "Poland",
      "RF"),
    labels = c(
      "Латвия (левая ось)", 
      "Литва (левая ось)",
      "Польша (левая ось)",
      "Россия (левая ось)"), 
    values = c(
      "#332288", 
      "#88CCEE",
      "#44AA99",
      "#117733"
      )) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5, size = 5, colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5, colour = "black"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_line(colour= "#ABABAB"),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"cm"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 5, angle = 90, colour = "black", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0,"cm"),
    legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.key.height = unit(.5, "cm"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    legend.box.margin = unit (c(-9,1,1,1), "mm"),
    plot.margin = unit (c(0,5,0,0), "mm")
    )
```

3. Then - for data points for the secondary Y axis:

```
p3.2right <- 
  subset.data.frame(
  data_3.2, 
  select = c(
    "date",
    "Ukraine")
  ) %>%
  
  ggplot(
    aes (
      x = date, 
      y= Ukraine,
      colour = "#999933"
      )
    ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(145,165), breaks = seq(145,165,5), expand = c(0.025,0)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "1 year") +
  geom_line(size = 1)+ 
  scale_colour_identity (
    guide = "legend", 
    label = "Украина (правая ось)",
      ) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5, size = 5, colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5, colour = "black"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_line(colour= "#ABABAB"),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"cm"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 5, angle = 90, colour = "black", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0,"cm"),
    legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.key.height = unit(.5, "cm"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
    legend.box.margin = unit (c(0,1,1,1), "mm"),
    plot.margin = unit (c(0,5,0,0), "mm")
    )
```

4. And finally I used the code that worked nicely before (but for some reasons stopped working now) that did what I need - put 2 plots on one chart:

```
# extract gtable
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p3.2left))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p3.2right))

# overlap the panel of 2nd plot on that of 1st plot
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t,
                     pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)
# axis tweaks
ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-r")
ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
ax <- ga$children[[2]]
ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)

g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)


#add legend to the code
leg1 <- g1$grobs[[which(g1$layout$name == "guide-box")]]
leg2 <- g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "guide-box")]]

leg = gtable:::cbind_gtable(leg1, leg2, "first")            
leg$widths[5:6] = unit(0, "cm")

g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")]] <- 
  gtable:::cbind_gtable(leg1, leg2, "first")
grid.draw(g)
```

I got the following error in the following line of the code:

```
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)

Error: grobs must either be a single grob or a list of grobs
```

I'm not good at 'gtable' package of R and would appreciate any support in correcting my code (or workflow) so that to finally build this chart and enhance my programming skills in R.

P.S.
I use R (Version 1.4.1717) on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: If you need to build *one* chart with 5 lines why are you putting two plots side by side?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a secondary y axis for the Ukraine data, then the following might solve the problem.
In order to make the main point more clear, I have simplified the code and removed the `scale_color_manual` and the `theme` from the plotting code. Instead, I have created a variable for the color and a custom theme.

The trick is to precompute a scaling factor `mult`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mult <- max(data_3.2[[6]])/max(data_3.2[2:5])

data_3.2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, color = name)) +
  geom_line(
    data = . %>% filter(name != "Ukraine"),
    aes(y = value),
    size = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = . %>% filter(name == "Ukraine"),
    aes(y = value/mult),
    size = 1
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(50, 80), 
    breaks = seq(50, 80, 5), 
    expand = c(0.025, 0),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      ~ . * mult, 
      name = "Ukraine",
      breaks = seq(70, 165, 5)
    )
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_color_dkolkin +
  theme_dkolkin()
```

[image]

---

### Color

```
scale_color_dkolkin <- scale_colour_manual (
  guide = "legend", 
  name = NULL,
  breaks = c(
    "Latvia",
    "Lithuania",
    "Poland",
    "RF",
    "Ukraine"
  ),
  labels = c(
    "Латвия (левая ось)", 
    "Литва (левая ось)",
    "Польша (левая ось)",
    "Россия (левая ось)",
    "Украина (правая ось)"
  ), 
  values = c(
    "#332288", 
    "#88CCEE",
    "#44AA99",
    "#117733",
    "#999933"
  ))
```

---

### Custom theme

```
theme_dkolkin <- function(){ 
  theme_bw() %+replace%    #replace elements we want to change
    theme(
      axis.text = element_text(size = 5, colour = "black"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5),
      axis.line.y = element_line(colour= "#ABABAB"),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 5, angle = 90, colour = "black", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
      axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"cm"),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.direction = "vertical", 
      legend.title = element_blank(),
      legend.spacing.x = unit(0,"cm"),
      legend.key = element_blank(),
      legend.key.height = unit(.5, "cm"),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
      legend.box.margin = unit (c(0,1,1,1), "mm"),
      plot.margin = unit (c(0,5,0,0), "mm")
    )
}
```

---

### Data

```
data_3.2 <-
structure(list(date = 2012:2021, Latvia = c(77.21, 75.4, 75.1, 
68.77, 64.8, 63.81, 62.88, 62.36, 63.89, 65.36), Lithuania = c(67.97, 
65.62, 63.86, 59.54, 55.83, 54.14, 53.31, 51.94, 51.69, 51.25
), Poland = c(72.97, 72.83, 71.55, 65.86, 62.14, 60.8, 59.62, 
58.12, 58.94, 57.78), RF = c(71.41, 71.03, 72.95, 71.61, 69.7, 
70.29, 70.82, 71.18, 73, 72.69), Ukraine = c(148.29, 149.45, 
153.65, 162.92, 154.51, 153.99, 153.07, 150.26, 154.26, 156.25
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Gents, 

I have no words, just emotions. You helped me so much! Thank you for your time and efforts. 

I also see that my knowledge of R is primitive, and it makes me seriously think on how to improve it. But what is more important is that my approach towards problem-solving is much complicated than yours. You made my code look elegant and simple.

I have to ask your further support on how/what I should do in order to become more proficient in R coding (that is, books, online classes etc.). It would be nice to hear your thoughts. 

Thank you again!

Comment: @dkolkin Thanks! Glad to help. As for becoming more proficient in R, go to the main source, [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/). On the bottom left there are links to documentation material, including manuals and books that you can download for free.

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot your data longer, and use `facet_wrap` like this. First create the initial data frame:

```
## data
library(tidyverse)
df = rbind(c(2012,  77.21, 67.97,   72.97, 71.41,   148.29),
           c(2013,  75.40, 65.62,   72.83, 71.03,   149.45),
           c(2014,  75.10, 63.86,   71.55, 72.95,   153.65),
           c(2015,  68.77, 59.54,   65.86, 71.61,   162.92),
           c(2016,  64.80, 55.83,   62.14, 69.70,   154.51),
           c(2017,  63.81, 54.14,   60.80, 70.29,   153.99),
           c(2018,  62.88, 53.31,   59.62, 70.82,   153.07),
           c(2019,  62.36, 51.94,   58.12, 71.18,   150.26),
           c(2020,  63.89, 51.69,   58.94, 73.00,   154.26),
           c(2021,  65.36, 51.25,   57.78, 72.69,   156.25)) %>% 
  data.frame()
colnames(df) = c('Date', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Poland',   'Russian Federation',   'Ukraine')
df
```

That gives a data frame that looks like this

```
   Date Latvia Lithuania Poland Russian Federation Ukraine
1  2012  77.21     67.97  72.97              71.41  148.29
2  2013  75.40     65.62  72.83              71.03  149.45
3  2014  75.10     63.86  71.55              72.95  153.65
4  2015  68.77     59.54  65.86              71.61  162.92
5  2016  64.80     55.83  62.14              69.70  154.51
6  2017  63.81     54.14  60.80              70.29  153.99
7  2018  62.88     53.31  59.62              70.82  153.07
8  2019  62.36     51.94  58.12              71.18  150.26
9  2020  63.89     51.69  58.94              73.00  154.26
10 2021  65.36     51.25  57.78              72.69  156.25
```

Then put this data in long form

```
## Pivot longer
df.long = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=-Date,
               names_to='Country', 
               values_to='value') 

## Create a column that is Ukraine or other
df.long = df.long %>%
  mutate(Category = ifelse(Country=='Ukraine', 'Ukraine', 'Other Countries'))
head(df.long)
```

That gives this

```
A tibble: 6 x 4
   Date Country            value Category       
  <dbl> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>          
1  2012 Latvia              77.2 Other Countries
2  2012 Lithuania           68.0 Other Countries
3  2012 Poland              73.0 Other Countries
4  2012 Russian Federation  71.4 Other Countries
5  2012 Ukraine            148.  Ukraine        
6  2013 Latvia              75.4 Other Countries
```

Now plot this using facet_wrap, which creates a new window for each value of "Category". Specify that you don't want to y-axes to be on the same scale by using `scales = 'free_y'`:

```
ggplot(df.long, aes(x=Date, y=value, group=Country, color=Country))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~Category, nrow=1, scales='free_y')
```

That gives this plot

[image]

Comment: Gents, 

I have no words, just emotions. You helped me so much! Thank you for your time and efforts. 

I also see that my knowledge of R is primitive, and it makes me seriously think on how to improve it. But what is more important is that my approach towards problem-solving is much complicated than yours. You made my code look elegant and simple.

I have to ask your further support on how/what I should do in order to become more proficient in R coding (that is, books, online classes etc.). It would be nice to hear your thoughts. 

Thank you again!

Comment: You are quite welcome. Glad I could help! One potential resources is the book R for Data Science https://r4ds.had.co.nz/. I haven't read this book yet, but I've heard good things about it.

Comment: I guess one general comment is that the approach of pivoting data into "long form" tends to be really useful in a lot of cases when using ggplot.